# Redirecting non-WWW to WWW in AWS not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

I tried to set a redirection from a non-WWW domain to a WWW domain.
For this thread, my domain is `example.com`.
So I want to redirect `example.com` to `www.example.com`.
All the resources in this thread are also HTTPS-protocol based.

I understood that I needed to set an S3 bucket for this.
So I've created a bucket called `example.com`.
I configured it as a static website hosting with public permissions:
[image]

I also configured it to redirect to another domain:
[image]

Then in Route53 I have 2 relevant entries under `xxx.com` domain:

The first one is to capture the `xxx.com` domain and forward it to the S3 bucket:
[image]

The second one is to capture the `example.xxx.com` domain and forward it to my load balancer (which then forwards it to my ECS cluster..):
[image]

So it seems for me all configuration is correct. However, I have been waiting for 2 days for the DNS propagation delay. But still: I cannot access via: `https://example.com`. I can access the S3 bucket public url (`Bucket website endpoint`) - which is also set in the route53 as an alias for non-WWW domain. And I can access `https://www.example.com`. Only non-WWW domains won't work: I get timeout..

Any advice?

---

I've also doing the same thing using load balancer for this redirection.

I've set the Route53 to forward the "example.com" domain to my load balancer.
[image]

Then in the load balancer configuration I set:
[image]

So now when I type: "example.com" I can access my web application, but I get routed to "https://example.com" - and not to WWW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not using your ALB to do his for you? Point both, www and non-www to your ALB and create a rule to check the Host like this one:
[image]

Please add this rule to port 443, there might be issue.

For Port 80 I redirect directly to the correct host, like www.{host]...

For the rules in 443 I do the redirect explicit like shown in my screenshot.

Most browser add the https protocol by default, so just typing example.com will be requested as example.com instead of some years ago example.com

Comment: It didn't work. I added screenshots of what I've tried to do

Comment: @Tal Rofe please also add this rule to port 443, there might be issue. For Port 80 I redirect directly to the correct host, like www.{host]... For the rules in 443 I do the redirect explicit like I send my screenshot. Most browser add the https protocol by default, so just typing example.com will be requested as https://example.com instead of some years ago http://example.com

Comment: Might be helpful if you'd edit your answer and provide full details

Answer (score 0):

You'll also need your ACM to list both `*.example.com` and `example.com` to be able to accomplish this. In addition, you'll need to configure your HTTPS listener to include both certificates in the accepted domains.

One of them will need to be the default and the other one will be an additional one. This way you can point your DNS entries to each one individually and pointing to the ELB.